# How to estimate the confidence interval for a proportion of two estimated values?

Tags: confidence-interval

I have estimated two values and confidence intervals (CIs), how can I estimate the CI of its ratio?

For example, a new method has been developed claiming to reduce SO2 emission in power plants by 20%. To test whether the claim is true, the method has been tested in 50 power plants. SO2 emission level has been measured and averaged for 5 consecutive days immediately before and another 5 consecutive days after the implementation of the new method. I used a linear mixed effect model to model the effect of implementation on the SO2 level, ie, Y is SO2 level, X is whether the implementation is in place (yes/no), and plant id is the random effect.
R code:

```R
library(lmerTest)
library(emmeans)
fit2<-lmer(Y~X+(1+X|Index)+temperature+Dew_point+Wind_spd+wind_dir+visibility+precip,
      data=hebing3, control=lmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=20000))
      ) ##X and meteorological conditions as fixed effects, Index as random effect.
fit2.means<-ref_grid(fit2)
res.means<-emmeans(fit2.means,"X") #### obtain estimated marginal means
```

Result:
The Coefficient for X is -22.46 (95% CI: -26.69, -18.24). We also obtained an adjusted, estimated pre-implementation SO2 level (92.75 (86.63, 98.87)) from the result using the function `emmeans` (see above), which is capable of computing estimated marginal means of X. Thus the new method reduces SO2 emission by 24.2% (22.46/92.75=0.242). However, I would like to estimate the 95% CI for this proportion, but there seems no existing way to do this. Can someone help me with it? Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the pre-implementation level was estimated using the function "emmeans". Auto-correction issue. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

There is a recent solution for this problem by Donner & Zhou named *MOVER-R* (published in 2012). There is even a readily available R implementation in the package *pairwiseCI*:

https://rdrr.io/cran/pairwiseCI/man/MOVERR.html